# How to tokenize shell input?

Tags: c, awk, posix

I've written my own shell that can execute a trivial command pipeline including arguments:

```
$ ls | wc -l
84
```

But with awk it is not working:

```
$ ls | awk '{print $1}'
awk: cmd. line:1: '{print
awk: cmd. line:1: ^ invalid char ''' in expression
```

The relevant code that handles the command-line is:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    char line2[BUFFER_LEN];
    char linecopy[BUFFER_LEN];
    char* params[100];
    int argc2 = 0;
    char *token;
    char *less_token;
    int i=0;
    char *tokenstr;
    char *search = " ";
    int isBackground = 0;
    int built_in_command = 0;
    int fd[2];
/*    long time;*/
    int status = 0;
    int max = 80;
    int b;
    struct passwd *pw;
    const char *homedir;
    struct timeval time_start;
    struct timeval time_end;
    sigset_t my_sig;
    pid_t pid_temp;
    char * pathValue;
    char * path_strdup;
    struct sigaction sa, osa;
    char *p;
    char *array[40];
    char line[BUFFER_LEN];
    size_t length;
    int ki;
    int ret;
    struct sigaction less_sa;
    err_setarg0(argv[argc-argc]);
    pid_temp = 0; /* To please the compiler */

    sa.sa_sigaction = sighandler;
    sa.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO;
    sigaction(SIGINT, &sa, &osa);

    less_sa.sa_handler = &handle_sigchld;
    sigemptyset(&less_sa.sa_mask);
    less_sa.sa_flags = SA_RESTART | SA_NOCLDSTOP;
    if (sigaction(SIGCHLD, &less_sa, 0) == -1) {
        perror(0);
        exit(1);
    }

    /* get the PATH environment to find if less is installed */
    pathValue = getenv("PATH");
    if (! pathValue) {
        printf ("'%s' is not set.\n", "PATH");
    }
    else {
       /* printf ("'%s' is set to %s.\n", "PATH", pathValue);*/
    }
    path_strdup = strdup(pathValue);
    less_token = strtok(path_strdup, ":");
    ret = 1;
    ret = findless(less_token, ret);
    free(path_strdup);
    while(1) {
        i = 0;
        printf("$ ");
        fflush(stdout);
        if (!fgets(line, BUFFER_LEN, stdin))
        {
            putchar('\n');
            break;
        }

        if (AllWhiteSpace(line))
            continue;

        strncpy(line2, line, BUFFER_LEN);
        strncpy(linecopy, line, BUFFER_LEN);

        length = strlen(line);
        if (line[length - 1] == '\n') {
            line[length - 1] = '\0';
        }
        if(strcmp(line, "exit")==0) {
            break;
        }
        if(StartsWith(line, "cd")) {
            built_in_command=1;
            if(strstr(line, " ") == NULL) {
                pw = getpwuid(getuid());
                homedir = pw->pw_dir;

                if (chdir(homedir)==-1) {   /*Change to home directory*/
                    perror("Failed changing to homedirectory\n");
                }
            } else {
                tokenstr = strtok(NULL, search);
                if (chdir(tokenstr)==-1)    {
                    perror("Failed changing directory\n");
                }

            }
        }
        token = strtok(line," ");
        while(token!=NULL) {
            params[i]=token;
            token = strtok(NULL," ");
            i++;
        }
        if(StartsWith(line, "checkEnv")) {
            built_in_command=1;
            checkEnv(ret);
        }
        if(0==built_in_command) {   /*Not a built in command, so let execute it*/

            params[i]=NULL;
            for(i=0; i<argc2; i++) {
                printf("%s\n", params[i]);
            }

            isBackground = 0;

            for (b = 0; b<max; b++) {
                if ('&'==line[b])   {
                    isBackground = 1;
                }
            }
            if (isBackground == 1)  {   /*If backgroundprocess*/

                if (pipe(fd)==-1)   {  /*(two new file descriptors)*/
                    perror("Failed creating pipe\n");
                }

                pid_temp = fork();
            }
            else if (isBackground == 0) {   /*If foreground process*/
                gettimeofday(&time_start, NULL);

                if (1 == isSignal)  {   /*If using signaldetection*/
                    sigemptyset(&my_sig); /*empty and initialising a signal set*/
                    sigaddset(&my_sig, SIGCHLD);    /*Adds signal to a signal set (my_sig)*/
                    /*http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/sigprocmask.html*/
                    sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, &my_sig, NULL);
                }

                pid_temp = fork();
                foreground = pid_temp;  /*Set pid for foreground process*/
            }
            if (0<pid_temp) {
                /*Parent process*/
            }
            else if (0>pid_temp)    {
                /*Error*/
            }
            else    {
                /*Child process*/
                if (1 == isBackground)  {   /*Backgroundprocess*/
                    dup2(fd[STDIN_FILENO], STDIN_FILENO);
                    close(fd[0]);
                    close(fd[1]);
                }

                length = strlen(linecopy);
                if (linecopy[length - 1] == '\n')
                    linecopy[length - 1] = '\0';

                /*printf("Command line: %s\n", linecopy);*/
                ki = 1;
                p = strtok(linecopy, " ");

                array[0] = NULL;
                while (p != NULL)
                {
                    array[ki++] = p;
                    p = strtok(NULL, " ");
                }
                array[ki] = NULL;
                /*dump_argv("Before exec_arguments", ki, array);*/
                exec_arguments(ki, array);
                corpse_collector();


            }
            if (0 == isBackground) {    /*Foregroundprocess*/
                waitpid(foreground, &status, 0);    /*Waiting*/
                /*Foregroundprocess terminated*/

                gettimeofday(&time_end, NULL);
/*                time = (time_end.tv_sec  - time_start.tv_sec) * 1000000 +
                       time_end.tv_usec - time_start.tv_usec;*/
                /*printf("Execution time %ld.%03ld ms\n", time / 1000, time % 1000);*/

                if (1 == isSignal)  {   /*If using signaldetection*/
                    int a = sigprocmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, &my_sig, NULL);
                    /*http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigprocmask.2.html*/
                    if (0 == a) {
                        /*Sigprocmask was successfull*/
                    }
                    else    {
                        /*Sigprocmask was not successfull, return=-1*/
                    }
                    Janitor(SIGCHLD);
                }
            }
            else if (1==isBackground)   {
                close(fd[0]);
                close(fd[1]);
            }
        }
        built_in_command = 0;   /*Reset*/
        memset(line, 0, sizeof line); /*Reset*/
    }
    return (0);
}
```

The entire program is available [here](http://pastebin.com/XHv1444Z).

How can I make my pipeline work? When I debug it, it looks like this:

```
$ ./a.out 
$ ls | wc -l
Before exec_arguments: (5) {(null)} {ls} {|} {wc} {-l}
84
27363: child 27364 status 0x0000
$ ls | awk '{print $1}'
Before exec_arguments: (6) {(null)} {ls} {|} {awk} {'{print} {$1}'}
awk: cmd. line:1: '{print
awk: cmd. line:1: ^ invalid char ''' in expression
27374: child 27375 status 0x0100
$
```

### "Solution"

My "solution" is to force the loop when there is an awk. Perhaps it is not ideal, but it will enable awk in the pipeline:

```
$ ls | awk '{print $1}'
alias.h
a.out
Boot1.asm
Boot1.bin
boot.asm
boot.bin
bootl.asm
bootload.asm
bootload.bin
bootloader
bootloader.asm
```

My new code that does the tokenizing is

```
        token = strtok(input, " ");
        i = 1;
        j=1;
        params[0] = NULL;
        while (token != NULL)
        {
            if(awk == 1) {
                s = concat("awk ", token);
                printf("s is %s", s);
                params[i++] = token;
                token = strtok(NULL, " ");
                awk = 0;
                continue;

            }
            if (strcmp(token, "awk") == 0) {
                params[i++] = token;
                awk = 1;
                token = strtok(NULL, "\'");
                continue;
            }

            params[i++] = token;
            token = strtok(NULL, " ");
        }
        params[i] = NULL;
        printf("ki %d", i);
        /*dump_argv("Before exec_arguments", i, params);*/
        exec_arguments(i, params);
        corpse_collector();
        free(input);
```

### Update

According to the answer by tripleee, I can use that pseudocode and implement parsing and stripping the quotes. This is as far as I got for now, and it compiles and works for some inputs. I hope that I don't misunderstand if I think that `push` means a stack operation so I added a stack for `char *` to my project which appears to work.

```
int handleToken(char input[BUFFER_LEN], char *token, char *params[100], int i) {

    int state = 0;
    char separator = ' ';
    int end_quote = 0;
    char dest[BUFFER_LEN];
    char *ptr;
    int pos = 0;
    char *ptr2;

    while (token != NULL) {
        if (state == 0) {
            if (1 == StartsWith(token, "'")) {
                state = 1;
                separator = '\'';
                ptr2 = strstr (input,token);
                if (ptr2 != NULL)
                {
                    pos = ptr2 - input;
                }
                if (subString (input, pos+1,  strlen (input)-pos-2, dest))  {
                    params[i++] = dest;
                    token = strtok(NULL, &separator);
                    continue;
                }
            }
            if (1 == StartsWith(token, "\"")) {
                state = 2;
                separator = '\"';
                continue;
            }
            params[i++] = token;
            token = strtok(NULL, &separator);
        }
        else if (state == 1) {
            ptr = strchr(token, '\'');
            if (ptr) {
                end_quote = ptr - token;
            }
            push(token);
            params[i++] = token;
            token = strtok(NULL, &separator);
            printf("%d", end_quote);
            state = 0;
        }
    }
    params[i] = NULL;
    return i;
}
/* double-quoted is similar but more complex */
```

Test

```
$ echo 'foo bar'
Before exec_arguments: (3) {(null)} {echo} {foo bar}
foo bar
2901: child 2922 status 0x0000
Execution time 1.872 ms
```

But this is not yet working:

```
$ echo 'a b' | awk '{print $1}'
Before exec_arguments: (3) {(null)} {echo} {a b' | awk '{print $1}}
a b' | awk '{print $1}
2901: child 2993 status 0x0000
Execution time 0.734 ms
```

Comment: Are you removing the quotation before passing arguments to programs? Check arguments passed using a simple program [like this](http://codepad.org/4hioAc61) and compare them with ones passed from commpnly used shell such as Bash or Zsh.

Comment: @MikeCAT I don't think I do. This is how debug looks: `(6) {(null)} {ls} {|} {awk} {'{print} {$}'}` i e length of array (6), empty first element, next elements are commands and arguments. In this case, awk gets its program as an argument when it should receive it as input instead.

Comment: @MikeCAT It looks as if it is tokenized at whitespace and that the `print` statement of awk gets messed up because the whitespace between `print` and `$1` gets interpreted as an argument separator.

Comment: Now you see the issue, so try to fix it.

Comment: @MikeCAT I found a tutorial that seems good that uses flex https://brskari.wordpress.com/2012/04/29/writing-a-basic-shell-using-flex-and-lemon-part-1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your shell should strip quotes after parsing them. The quotes around the script are not part of the Awk language; their purpose is to protect the Awk script from being parsed in any way by the shell. The correct end result is

```
char *cmd[] = { "/usr/bin/awk", "{ print $1 }", 0 };
```

A full parser for shell needs to cope with recursive structures, but quoted strings should require only minor modifications to your code. Basically, in pseudocode

```
while token:
  if state == regular:
    if token.startswith("'"):
      state := single_quoted_string
      redo
    elsif token.startswith("\""):
      state := double_quoted_string
      redo
    # else
    push parsed, token
    token := next_token
  elsif state == single_quoted_string:
    end_quote := indexof("'")
    push parsed, substr(token+1, end_quote-1) # omit quotes
    token := end_quote + 1
    state := regular
  else:
    # double-quoted is similar but more complex
```

Comment: I'm trying to implement this pseudocode now to make it run and will compare my efforts to execute code that was scanned using flex and the tutorial with flex and the lemon parser.

Comment: I understand that reserved keywords for the shell won't work (like a while loop won't work) and that is out of scope for this question.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is do with escaping quotes when you are passing it as arguement to execvp.

Wrote a small pgm to just check the  mechanism to pass quoted arguments to  execvp  For e.g code had following layout

```
  char *cmd2[] = { "/usr/bin/awk", " \' { print $1 } \'",  0 };
  excvp (cmd2[0], cmd) ;
```

The error that was thrown was similar  to what you obtained

```
 awk:  ^ invalid char ''' in expression
```

Escaping ' (as in \') , or not escaping did not make any difference to the  result  that was output

However When the above was changed to  ( single quote changed to escaped double quotes)

```
char *cmd2[] = { "/usr/bin/awk", " \" { print $1 } \"",  0 };
excvp (cmd2[0], cmd) ;
```

Things worked great. (The above command will echo whatever you type in shell)

So I guess you need to parse the arguments of awk  and look for  single-quotes , create a new *cmd* string where these quotes are replaced by  \". Guess your error is comming, as you are  passing the  parameters entered by user "as is" without formatting (as  mentioned above)

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I downloaded the source for bash shell to see how they do it, the bash shell source was 8 MB....wonder what it does that makes it so large.

Comment: No, this is completely up the wall.  The quotes **are not part of the Awk script** - they are required with normal shells to prevent the *shell* from picking apart the argument, but they should be removed completely by the shell.  You want `char *cmd[] = { "/usr/bin/awk", "{ print $1 }", 0 }`.  The double quotes will "fix" the syntax error and produce a true string; it's functionally equivalent to `awk '"trvth"'` which will print every line because `"trvth"` is a non-empty scalar -- so it's further equivalent to `awk 1`

Comment: @tripleee I see. Now I think that I might need a regex or similar to parse the awk part since awk can be followed by its own program. I'll be glad to learn more if you can tell me more how to do it. I'm currently tokenizing the command-line at whitespace. I included a link to the complete program (16 K).

Comment: Quoting should prevent tokenization on whitespace. Your original code looked more correct, except your program left the quotes in place. Regex is almost certainly the wrong approach here.

Comment: Bash has an extensive set of features, but the only part you need to understand is the parser, which was a reasonably standard Bison grammar last time I looked. If you are not familiar with Yacc / Bison, you have a rather steep mountain to climb before you see what it does, though.

Comment: First google hit, pretty old version, but probably older is simpler is better. http://opensource.apple.com//source/bash/bash-29/bash/parse.y

Comment: Further, http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashParser and https://github.com/idank/bashlex and http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/grammar/parser_exec

Comment: @tripleee Wow, that is a lot of theory and code to solve the problem. I never actually used yacc but I know some of the theory from books. That simpler grammar is many times larger than my entire program. I suppose I can begin with learning bison and the details of the bourne shell. I don't think that there is an easy solution to my problem because there are so many combinations of input.

Comment: The heavy stuff is for nested structures, like command substitutions inside command substitutions, nested subshells, functions, etc. For a simple pipeline parser, you can probably get by without a real grammar.

Comment: @tripleee Can I do it with the Gnu Readline library or similar library? I'm currently trying to build the dash shell which is a small shell that I can learn from, but the thing is not very modular and I'm not familiar with Ubuntu/Debian's build system. I can build dash with make and look at it, but I want to build with cmake.

Comment: Readline is for history and stuff.  All you need for quoted strings is a `strtok` loop with two states (or three, to distinguish single and double quotes).

Comment: @tripleee Thank you for following up my question. I found a tutorial how to parse the shell language using flex: https://brskari.wordpress.com/2012/04/29/writing-a-basic-shell-using-flex-and-lemon-part-1/ I'm trying to learn flex and scan and parse the shell language based on that tutorial. But if you say I can manage this if I make a two-state `strtok` then I want to try that but I don't have an idea how to implement those states yet. If you want to have a look at my code for my shell so far this is the link https://github.com/montao/openshell